# как запустить сокет-сервер на хостинге

Tags: php, websocket

я создал сайт "pg-tst.tk" на хостинге 000webhost.com.

написал локальный чат на php сокетах на этом [примере](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket) и добавил рисовалку. Но вот только он работает локально. Как его можно заставить работать на хостинге?

чат клиент готов http://pg-tst.tk/sasha2/full_chat.php, но вот только осталось запустить демона на хостинге

пока он работает с open server. Указал домен site.ru. Вот пример создания сервера

```
//test.php
$host = 'site.ru'; //host
$port = '9000'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
socket_listen($socket);

$clients = array($socket);

while(true){
  //...
}
```

что бы скрипт заработал нужно на него зайти

включаю openserver и захожу на site.ru/sasha2/test.php

а уже через js подключаюсь

```
 ws = new WebSocket('ws://site.ru:9000/sasha2/demo/test.php')
```

Все нормально работает

Затем на хостинге захожу на pg-tst.tk/sasha2/test.php

подключаюсь через js. пишет ошибку

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://pg-tst.tk:9000/sasha2/demo/test.php')
WebSocket connection to 'ws://pg-tst.tk:9000/sasha2/demo/test.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Пробовал привязать сервер к ip $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR]; но айпишник странный 2a02:4780:bad:12::261 js ругается на такой адрес, а если через $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] идет бесконечная загрузка.

Короче не удается запустить сервер test.php на хостинге. Может быть хостинг запрещает запускать сокеты?

Comment: В вашем примере прямо сказано зайти на сервер и запустить сокет-сервер командой типа `php -q c:\path-to-server\server.php`. Если у вас нет возможности это сделать, меняйте хостинг на тот, который аткую возможность предоставляет.

Comment: Почему нельзя зайти на server и скрипт запуститься? Хоть 30 сек, но все равно хоть что то.

Comment: Спросите в поддержке хостинга. Только они скорее всего вам скажут "мы такое не поддерживаем" и всё :)

Comment: А какой хостинг может поддерживать сокет-сервер?

Comment: Любой VPS или VDS. Полноценная машина.

Comment: Я имел в виду сайт хостинг, где уже все есть. Типо GoDaddy или hostinger

Comment: Любой, где вы можете получить целую машину.

Comment: Перешел на vps на Ubuntu 46.101.253.109/sasha/full_chat.php и все равно не хочет подключаться( просто идет долгая загрузка и ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
пока написал в саппорт

Comment: что за `bullshit` :D?

Comment: всмысле bullshit? это чат где можно рисовать вместе онлайн

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в firewall и в портах!!!!

```
sudo ufw allow 9228
```

отключить firewall

```
sudo ufw disable
```

перезагрузить

```
reboot
```