# Как опубликовать сайт на хостинг?

Tags: php, workerman

У меня есть сайт, в котором используется веб-сокеты. Сервер написан на PHP с использованием Workerman. Но чтобы сайт работал, мне нужно сначала запустить сервер командой `php server.py` и подключиться к нему в js таким образом `const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2346");`.
При таком раскладе все работает хорошо, но мне нужно залить сайт на хостинг и в таком случае уже непонятно как запускать сервер и нужно ли его вообще запускать, что писать вместо `"ws://localhost:2346"`. Я новичок в php, поэтому прошу мне помочь!

Comment: Нашел ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706437/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b5?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Сначала выясни, разрешено ли на хостинге использовать сокеты. Большинство хостеров запрещают использовать сокеты...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: разрешено на vps